# Pattern matching in haskell for lists

Tags: haskell

[Noob question]
I have a list in haskell with only two elements :

```
mylist = ["Apple", "Mango"]
```

When I try to do pattern matching like this

```
[firstelemet ,secondelement] = mylist;
```

I get this kind of warning.

> warning: [-Wincomplete-uni-patterns]
>       Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
>       In a pattern binding:
>           Patterns not matched:
>               []
>               [*]
>               (*:*:*:_)

Any suggestions on how this can be done in a better way. Actually I need to do this for unit testing that returns a list with two elements.

Comment: You better use tuples.

Comment: Actually I need to do this for unit testing that returns a list with two elements.

Comment: Since you are doing it for unit testing, you should also test it is indeed a list of two elements. E.g. something like `case mylist of [x,y] -> actualTest x y ; _ -> testFailed`

Comment: How about not using pattern matching and using something like `returnedList = myList` and then asserting that `returnedList` has length two? If the individual elements need to be accessed, they can be done using `returnedList !! 0` or `returnedList !! 1`

Answer (score 3):

When teaching people to unit test in ML-based languages, I often get the question on how to verify a monadic value. Is that what's you're trying to do here?

The question is often a variation on:

*How do I get the value out of the monad?*

My answer is typically:

*You don't. You step into the monad.*

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
assertEquals "Apple" firstelement
assertEquals "Mango" secondelement
```

Here, I'm assuming that you have some sort of `assertEquals` function...

If so, it helps to realise that Haskell lists are `Eq` when elements are `Eq`, so instead, you could just write something like this:

```
assertEquals ["Apple", "Mango"] mylist
```

If that doesn't work for you, you could introduce a little helper function like this:

```
tryPair :: [a] -> Maybe (a, a)
tryPair [x, y] = Just (x, y)
tryPair _      = Nothing
```

This would enable you to first do this:

```
m = tryPair mylist
```

`Maybe a` is also `Eq` if `a` is `Eq`, so you could write your assertion like this:

```
assertEquals (Just ("Apple", "Mango")) m
```

If this *still* doesn't work for you, perhaps you could write a test utility function like this:

```
assertJust :: Maybe a -> (a -> ()) -> ()
assertJust (Just x) f = f x
assertJust Nothing _ = assertFail "Boo! Nothing!"
```

This would enable you to write something like this:

```
assertJust (tryPair mylist) $ \(x, y) -> assertEquals "Apple" x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as

```
mylist = ["Apple", "Mango"]
firstelement : secondelement : _ = mylist
```

to get the exact thing that you want, though the other approaches suggested here are probably better, conceptually. Note that this will only work with lists of at least 2 elements.